# Gitlab dendency scan not supported: package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following code in Gitlab job for dependency scanning:

```
gemnasium-dependency_scanning:
  rules:
    - when: on_success
  dependencies: ["nodejs_build"]
```

Output of */analyzer run*

```
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T10:11:55Z] ▶ GitLab Gemnasium analyzer v4.10.3
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T10:12:05Z] ▶ Using commit 200ff9f84d1d4620767b036b3803a03b6c2174f0
 of vulnerability database
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T10:12:06Z] ▶ using schema model 15
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T10:12:06Z] ▶ Cannot auto-remediate dependency file, not supported: package-lock.json
```

Mine *lockfileVersion": 3*

**Does it mean, scan was not realized because of unsupported package-lock.json?**

Job output:

```
$ /analyzer run
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T15:14:09Z] ▶ GitLab Gemnasium analyzer v4.10.3
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T15:14:19Z] ▶ Using commit 9d7ca075a04f32d6b9b60d310c119011f65c9b22
 of vulnerability database
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T15:14:20Z] ▶ using schema model 15
[INFO] [Gemnasium] [2024-01-11T15:14:20Z] ▶ Cannot auto-remediate dependency file, not supported: package-lock.json
Saving cache for successful job 00:01
Creating cache default-1-non_protected...
./*.json: found 11 matching artifact files and directories 
./*.js: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
./node_modules: found 585 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading cache.zip to https://obs.eu-de.otc.t-systems.com/obs-prod-gitlab-runner-cache/obs-prod-gitlab-runner-cache/project/238936/default-1-non_protected 
Created cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job 00:02
Uploading artifacts...
**/gl-sbom-*.cdx.json: found 2 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=147084393 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_qxkgT
Uploading artifacts...
**/gl-sbom-*.cdx.json: found 2 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "cyclonedx" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=147084393 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_qxkgT
Uploading artifacts...
gl-dependency-scanning-report.json: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "dependency_scanning" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=147084393 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_qxkgT
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
Job succeeded
```

Comment: It's just an informational message that means it could not generate auto remediations (the fixes to address vulnerabilities in your dependencies). What is the complete output of the job? Are there any errors or does the job fail?

Comment: No errors, see job output in edited ticket. File `gl-dependency-scanning-report.json` was not found in Artifacts (only `gl-sbom-*.cdx.json`) + no vulnerability report in Gitlab UI